# Are there any APIs to create "Main - Sub report" by using WebdataRocks

Tags: java, api, webdatarocks

We are using WebDataRocks to create our web report. But I am wondering if WebDataRock has certain API I can use to cover our "Main - Sub report" scenario?
Basically, this scenario will be something like:

1. There is a main report, for certain data (aggregration or even grand Total), we enabled link on them, click those link will open(run) another report(sub report).
2. When click Link of main report, some necessary information(agg based field name or other things) will be collected, then passed to subreport as parameters, then subreport opens.

This kind like Drill down of WebDataRocks, but more flexible and can be used to create any kind of (main - sub) report.

All in all, I guess I just want to know two things:

1. Does WebDataRocks has API to create customized link for Aggregation and that link is point to another WebDataRocks report template
2. Can WebDataRocks be executed by a API call, and accept certain parameters? and those parameters might be used as parameters of SQL query

I check all document of WebDataRocks, nothing even close. So, just want to know if above is even possible?

Thankss